# How to use echo with blocks of html

Tags: php

i want to use this code inside echo in php.

```
 <div id="ib-main-wrapper" class="ib-main-wrapper">
 <div class="ib-main">
 <a href="#">
 <img src="images/upload/Desert.jpg" data-largesrc="images/upload/Desert.jpg"  
 alt="image01"/><span>Crabbed Age and Youth</span></a>
```

Please suggest

Comment: Don't do it! You should use templates and never output HTML right from PHP.

Comment: I prefer using output buffers, as I can place any php code inside. See my answer.

Answer (score 8):

Use [`heredoc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

```
echo <<<EOT
 <div id="ib-main-wrapper" class="ib-main-wrapper">
 <div class="ib-main">
 <a href="#">
 <img src="images/upload/Desert.jpg" data-largesrc="images/upload/Desert.jpg"  
 alt="image01"/><span>Crabbed Age and Youth</span></a>
EOT;
```

Comment: @user2028580 Are you facing some issue? I  don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple. Try the below code

```
echo '<div id="ib-main-wrapper" class="ib-main-wrapper">
                <div class="ib-main">
 <a href="#"><img src="images/upload/Desert.jpg" data-largesrc="images/upload/Desert.jpg" alt="image01"/><span>Crabbed Age and Youth</span></a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to heredoc is using [Output buffers](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php).

They work in the following way:

```
ob_start(); ?>
 <div id="ib-main-wrapper" class="ib-main-wrapper">
     <div class="ib-main">
         <a href="#">
             <img src="images/upload/Desert.jpg" data-largesrc="images/upload/Desert.jpg" alt="image01"/><span>Crabbed Age and Youth</span>
         </a>

    <?php
$result = ob_get_clean();
// you now have the full html in $result, and you can echo it
echo ob_get_clean();
// or just echo it
```

There is an advantage to heredoc - that you can use any PHP code inside.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<div id="ib-main-wrapper" class="ib-main-wrapper">
 <div class="ib-main">
 <a href="#">
 <img src="images/upload/Desert.jpg" data-largesrc="images/upload/Desert.jpg"  
 alt="image01"/><span>Crabbed Age and Youth</span></a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$str = <<<EOL
<div id="ib-main-wrapper" class="ib-main-wrapper">
                <div class="ib-main">
 <a href="#"><img src="images/upload/Desert.jpg" data-largesrc="images/upload/Desert.jpg" alt="image01"/><span>Crabbed Age and Youth</span></a>
EOL;

echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you mean, but there are tow ways to do it:

```
<?php echo '<div id="ib-main-wrapper" class="ib-main-wrapper">
<div class="ib-main">
<a href="#"><img src="images/upload/Desert.jpg" data-largesrc="images/upload/Desert.jpg" alt="image01"/><span>Crabbed Age and Youth</span></a>'; ?>
```

or even better:

```
<?php
//Insert more PHP code
?>
<div id="ib-main-wrapper" class="ib-main-wrapper">
<div class="ib-main">
<a href="#"><img src="images/upload/Desert.jpg" data-largesrc="images/upload/Desert.jpg" alt="image01"/><span>Crabbed Age and Youth</span></a>
<?php
//Even more PHP code
?>
```

Number two makes it easier to read in an editor with syntax highlighting.